# How to perform AND query in inner array document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I want to get all document where (`B.arrayC.X == 128` AND `B.arrayC.Y == 'PENDING'`)

Collection records are like below which contains an Array of Embedded Documents.

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(1),
    "A" : NumberLong(0),
    "B" : {
        "arrayC" : [ 
            {
                "X" : NumberLong(128),
                "Y" : "COMPLETED",
                "Z" : NumberLong(50)
            }, 
            {
                "X" : NumberLong(109),
                "Y" : "PENDING",
                "Z" : NumberLong(0)
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(2),
    "A" : NumberLong(0),
    "B" : {
        "arrayC" : [ 
            {
                "X" : NumberLong(128),
                "Y" : "PENDING",
                "Z" : NumberLong(50)
            }, 
            {
                "X" : NumberLong(109),
                "Y" : "PENDING",
                "Z" : NumberLong(0)
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried the below queries, all queries are returning none PENDING jobs.

```
db.getCollection('demo').find({"B.arrayC.X" : 128, "B.arrayC.Y" : "PENDING"})

db.getCollection('demo').find({"$and":[{"B.arrayC.X" : 128, "B.arrayC.Y" : "PENDING"}])

db.getCollection('demo').find({"$and":[{"B.arrayC.X" : 128}, {"B.arrayC.Y" : "PENDING"}])
```

What I understand is MongoDB returning `_id` 1 record due to `B.arrayC.X` record with 109 id have `"PENDING"` state in it.
What should be the correct query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *What I understand is MongoDB returning `_id` 1 record due to `B.arrayC.X` record with 109 id have "PENDING" state in it. What should be the correct query?*

As per your try both the field's conditions are separate and it will result document if `X` satisfied condition in any element of `arrayC` and if `Y` satisfied condition in any element of `arrayC`,

Try [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to match all the fields in every single element,

```
db.getCollection('demo').find({
  "B.arrayC": {
    $elemMatch: {
      X: 128,
      Y: "PENDING"
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kQghuQvpEtZ)